# WCF Dataservice hosting issue with vs2010

Tags: wcf, dataservice

I have created WCF Data service and I hosted in visual studio ASP.net development server.My problem is that my service will run only when I build my application through VS2010, if I try running exe using debug/release folder dataservice is not launching. It should run when I click on my application exe file.

Below code sinnpet describe how I starting my data service.

```
WebServiceHost dbServiceHost= new  WebServiceHost(typeof(MyDataService));
```

`dbServiceHost.Open();`

Any early help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `DataServiceHost` (in assembly `System.Data.Services`; descends from `WebServiceHost`) to host your WCF Data Service:

```
using System.Data.Services;

Uri[] baseAddresses = new Uri[1];
baseAddresses[0] = new Uri(baseAddress);

using(DataServiceHost host = new DataServiceHost(typeof(YourDataService), baseAddresses))
{
    host.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("DataService up and running.....");

    Console.ReadLine();
    host.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Marc.. But what is the problem if I use WebServiceHost. I dont understand what is the difference between WebServiceHost  and DataServiceHost

Comment: @Vinay MS; the `DataServiceHost` has some additional functionality it needs for a WCF DataService to work properly. If it's there, there must be a reason for it - so use it!